# GUID explanation - C++

Tags: c++, guid, uuid, declspec

I use a sample from windows to learn DirectShow, and in a class I have this code in the header file:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("{71771540-2017-11cf-ae26-0020afd79767}")) CLSID_TextureRenderer;
```

And this line in the cpp file:

```
CTextureRenderer::CTextureRenderer(LPUNKNOWN unk, HRESULT *hr): CBaseVideoRenderer(__uuidof(CLSID_TextureRenderer), "Texture Renderer", unk, hr)
```

Can you explain me how that all things work together?

Thank a lot.

Comment: The first is a definition of a class id, and the other extracts the uuid from the named struct (using a Microsoft extension). Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Microsoft Visual C++ extension to C++, to aid COM programming. `__declspec(uuid())` associates `GUID` structure with a class, and `__uuidof` yields `GUID` value of a given type/expression.